# in Javascript what does - valuesLength = (values.length , undefined); - do?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am using GWT and the translated javascript has this functionality in several places

```
valuesLength = (values.length , undefined);
```

I assumed that it was a set to `undefined` if object does exist but when debugging in the browser although values object exist and length has a value valuesLength always equals undefined.

Comment: That code you posted will generate a syntax error. Is the trailing fragment ")." really supposed to be there?

Comment: @Pointy I think that was the fault of the previous 'helpful' edit; the period is not intended to be part of the code, but was closing the sentence. I think perhaps the wrapping parens were the OP's way of setting aside the code, so I've removed them as well.

Comment: This is known as *"I want to be the only person that can maintain this"* code.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: If I'm reading it right, it's computer-generated code, created by [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/).

Comment: Wanted to add some information for anyone that every has this issue with GWT, make sure if the native function is returning a value you actually put a "return" statement in the code otherwise the GWT compiler will output the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the comma operator  evaluates its operands left to right and returns the value of rightmost operand.

```
(values.length , undefined)
               ^^                  // will output undefined
```

[MDN](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator&rct=j&q=javascript%20comma%20operator%20%5C&ei=_URdTqWvDsP10gHCn63hAg&usg=AFQjCNEm486t8SqFVf944TEWA-lreJ30Bg&cad=rja) reference (not working right now)

If the objective is to have check for object's existence, the right way to do that is

```
var valuesLength;
if(values && values.length) {
  valuesLength = values.length;
}
// else valuesLength will be undefined by default
```

Answer (score 1):

"The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand."

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

This code would appear to serve no purpose since `values.length` is only a property. If it were a method, then it could have side effects.

Most people don't use the comma operator because it creates confusing code. I suspect this is just an example of what is essentially a compiler producing weird code because its optimizer isn't perfect.